# Where does the Android Emulator store the SD-Card files?

Tags: android, emulation, sd-card

I want to make two emulators use the same SD-Card image. I automatically created a SD-Card in the first emulator and downloaded all the data to this SD-Card.

How can I load this SD-Card in another emulator? I don't want to recreate all the data on the SD-Card for every single emulator all the time.

Comment: Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it.

The android tools create an .android folder in your users home folder. This folder contains an avd folder in which a separate folder for each virtual device exists. In each of this folders a file called sdcard.img should be present. This file contains the automatically created sd card image for this AVD.

Answer (score 2):

the path usually is /mnt/sdcard