# Internal Storage access using emulator android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

i am wondering could i access my app internal storage using emulator. I mean that if there are somewhere on my computer folder of my created app. I know that on not rooted device i couldn't find, because Internal Storage store private data on the device memory.

But for me it would be easier to find that directory not only from code.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925018/where-does-the-android-emulator-store-the-sd-card-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your internal storage files can be found in `/data/data/your.app.package.goes.here/files/`. It is accessible in the emulator through DDMS or via commands like `adb push` and `adb pull`.